# Property to return separate month, day, year attributes formatted?

Tags: c#, date

This one has me stumped, since I don't think this can be done with a simple DateTime method, unless there's something I'm not understanding.

It should be simple like this: format the variables to read in the XX/XX/XXXX format and if one of these integers is 0, a console output should read ~~unspecified~~

```
   namespace TheTime
    {
        public class Time
        {
            private int month;
            private int day;
            private int year;

            public int Mont{}
            public int Day {}
            public int Year {}
```

Comment: Homework question :(. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to your `Time` class.

```
public string FormattedDate()
{
    if (month == 0 || day == 0 || year == 0)
        return string.empty;

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    return dt.ToString("d"); // returns mm/dd/yyyy
}
```

Then to use it:

```
string sDate = myTimeObj.FormattedDate();

if(sDate == string.empty)
{
   Console.WriteLine("~~unspecified~~");
}
else
{
   // it worked fine
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what exactly do you mean. But if you want to read a date from the console, and fail if it doesn't succeed, you can do something like this:

```
string dateString = …;
DateTime date;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(
    dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy",
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("~~unspecified~~");
    return;
}

//work with date
```

If `dateString` contained `0` in any of the parts, or if it was formatted incorrectly, this code writes `~~unspecified~~` and doesn't continue.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Time
{
     private int month;
     private int day;
     private int year;

     public override string ToString()
     {
           if(month == 0 || day == 0 || year == 0)
           {
                 return "~~unspecified~~";
           }
           DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
           return date.ToString();
     }
}
```

Comment: ooooh, similar to my answer but I like this better, +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the String using ReadLine

U can use ParseExact Method like this

```
DateTime yourdate = DateTime.ParseExact(your_read_string, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```